# different between Object.toString and Object.prototype.toString

Tags: javascript

We can use `Object.prototype.toString.call(foo)` to detect object class (the type of foo), and it works well.

But why does `Object.toString.call({})` throw `TypeError: Function.prototype.toString is not generic`?

Doesn't `Object.toString` inherit from `Object.prototype`?

Comment: Because toString is a prototype method and not a function static method.

Comment: `Object` is a `Function`, while `Object.prototype` is *the* object which everything inherits from.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Doesn't Object.toString inherit from Object.prototype

No. The built–in [*Object*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2) constructor is a Function (like all native constructors), so it inherits from *Function.prototype* (i.e. its private `[[Prototype]]` property references *Function.prototype*) before its own *prototype* property.

Its prototype chain is:

```
Object[[Prototype]] -> Function.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
```

so *Function.prototype.toString* masks *Object.prototype.toString*.

A bit of trivia: note that while *Function.prototype* is a function, it doesn't inherit from itself but from *Object.prototype*.

Comment: Just to make this clearer: `Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype`.

Comment: @RobG. > "while Function.prototype is a function" but IMHO, `constructor.prototype` are always `objects`. `Function.prototype.prototype` gives `undefined` which is correct, since pure objects (i.e. not function objects)  do not have a `prototype` property only function objects do however when I echo `Function.prototype` inside chrome's console it does echo `function () {}`. Can you plz throw some light as to why this gogglee-boggleness?

Comment: @dkjain—it's explained in [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object): "*The Function prototype object … is itself a built-in function object. … It does not have a [[Construct]] internal method so it is not a constructor.*" so does not have a default *prototype* property. It's a special case in that it's a built–in function that isn't a constructor. That is also possible for host functions, there is no requirement that they must be constructors (e.g. *Document.getElementById* is not a constructor in browsers I've tested).