# What is the different between Object.toString and Object.prototype.toString

Tags: javascript

```
{}.toString === Object.toString
```

This will return a false value while

```
{}.toString === Object.prototype.toString
```

is true.

we know that `{}` is a object literal , is it the same as `new Object` does? if this two things is equal,{}.toString and Object.toString should be the same, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [different between Object.toString and Object.prototype.toString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333923/different-between-object-tostring-and-object-prototype-tostring)

Comment: When you access `Object.toString`, you are accessing the method to convert the `Object` **constructor** to a string. When you access `Object.prototype.toString`, you are accessing the **function that will be given to each object**. `{}.toString` is **inherited from `Object.prototype`**, thus being the same.