# What different between Object.prototype.toString and toString?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

As we know, we can use the `Object.prototype.toString.call(arg)` if we need to detect object class.

But In my test, `Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === toString`.

So, why don't we use `toString.call(arg)` to replace `Object.prototype.toString.call(arg)` which is a long type.

In the [Polyfill of `Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), It also use `Object.prototype.toString.call(arg)`.

[different between Object.toString and Object.prototype.toString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333923/different-between-object-tostring-and-object-prototype-tostring)

Comment: These are totally different methods. `instance.toString` gives a string presentation of the instance of an object, and is often overridden. And as you've noticed, calling `Object.prototype.toString` gives a "Class" of the object. For example, consider the return values of `[].toString()` and `Object.prototype.toString.call([]);` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary, it just makes the code's intent more clear. When you use the `toString` standalone function, *usually* that'll refer to `window.toString` - `window` is an object, and objects inherit from `Object.prototype`, so `window.toString === Object.prototype.toString`. But relying on this sort of thing implicitly can be [confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776759/how-to-avoid-accidentally-implicitly-referring-to-properties-on-the-global-objec) and can produce bugs.

There's also no guarantee that there's not some *other* function you've defined called `toString`, eg:

```js
(() => {
  const toString = () => 'here is a string';
  
  // many lines of code here
  class Foo {}
  const f = new Foo();
  // Does not result in "[object Object]":
  console.log(toString.call(f));
})();
```

Explicitly using `Object.prototype.toString` instead makes the code more understandable and predictable at a glance.

(You're still free to use `toString` alone instead if you want, it *probably* won't break anything, but it's probably not a great idea in general.)

Comment: Why do you use an IIFE here?

Comment: @Kobe To avoid polluting the global namespace.

Comment: Not that important, it just distinguishes the locally scoped `toString` from the `toString` visible on the top level, though even if it was on the top level, It doesn't overwrite `window.toString` if it's declared with `const`. It doesn't really matter, just slightly reduces the possibility of confusion from looking at the snippet

Comment: And `window.toString` might not necessarily be `Object.prototype.toString` (or does the Web Spec say that?) ...

Comment: @JonasWilms Yeah, could be, that's why I said *usually*. `window.toString` is writable, it's not even a property of `window`, it's just inheriting from `Object.prototype`